# Where can I find a dataset of songs labeled with their genre, BPM and key?

Tags: data-request, music

I am mostly interested in electronic songs. I need both the songs' waveform and their labels (genre, BPM and key). If you know some similar data set that doesn't contain all 3 labels, please still share.

If possible, I want open data and downloading the whole dataset at once.

Comment: Do you want open data or is commercial OK? Is a web service OK, or do you want to download the whole dataset?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul if possible, open data and downloading the whole dataset.

Answer (score 9):

I haven't used them before. I've just had them in my bookmarks for any case.

1) http://echoprint.me/

Free: 'Use our data for whatever you want (commercial or non, research, personal use)'

2) http://the.echonest.com/

Free for non-commercial: The Echo Nest APIs are free for non-commercial purposes. To use them commercially, contact us and we will go over licensing options.

I think that both of them are services to identify a song like Shazam does. But they let you download their data or use their API.

Comment: First link is now dead :( And I can't see where to get access to the API on Echonest...

Answer (score 5):

columbia has a music db here: http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/pages/example-track-description
also check last.fm and creative commons music communities:
http://creativecommons.org/music-communities

Comment: Last.FM's genres would be sooo useful, but their API broke years ago, and they haven't fixed it, or given any indication that they will :( Pretty crap, too, because it's all community-supplied data..

Comment: probably not too hard to scrape

Answer (score 3):

[**AcousticBrainz**](https://acousticbrainz.org) is a database of algorithmically derived music metadata, including BPM, Key, moods, and genres. The database is keyed by acoustIDs, and you can find the acoustIDs for a particular track by searching for it on [MusicBrainz.org](http://www.musicbrainz.org).

#### Example: [Tipper - Bubble Control](https://acousticbrainz.org/9cfbf316-08ef-41bb-a603-d15913548c9b).

Most attributes have uncertainties associated with them, and it's worth noting that the algorithms involved are not fool proof. For example, the above track is tagged Voice (92%), even though it does not have vocals (it has lots of weird synthesised noises that sound similar to vocals though). It is also tagged Jazz (100%), and though it does share many attributes with jazz, I doubt many people would actually classify it as jazz. Also, it's listed as 100% not danceable, which I can personally attest is not true :P

The data shown on that page is only a subset of what is available through the API.

**All data is public domain** (and if a song doesn't exist, you can easily submit it yourself with scripts listed on the [contributing page](https://acousticbrainz.org/contribute)), and is accessible via JSON, via their API (no API key required).

You can download the entire database at https://acousticbrainz.org/download, but it's 2.5Gb for just the high-level data, 34Gb for the full dataset (there are multiple fingerprints for each song).